# How do you route within an Amazon VPC subnet?

Tags: routing, openvpn, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, subnet

I have an Amazon Virtual Private Cloud that looks like this:

```
10.40.1.1   Internet Gateway
10.40.1.5   My OpenVPN Instance
10.40.1.100 My Windows Box
```

What I want is traffic from the Windows box destined for network 10.200.1.0 to route through my OpenVPN Instance (10.40.1.5), but for the life of me I cannot make it go.

1. The Windows Box can ping the OpenVPN Instance.  The subnet and instances have appropriate firewall rules.
2. To test routing I run "ping 10.200.1.123" from the Windows box and watch the output of tcpdump on the OpenVPN Instance.  This technique works on my local physical LAN.
3. To the VPC route table I added a route for 10.200.1.0/24 to go to the OpenVPN Instance, but they never arrive.
4. On the Windows box I tried adding the same route.  Using wireshark I verified that ping packets are destined to the OpenVPN Instance's MAC address.  But no cigar.

Do VPC subnets even allow this kind of routing?

Comment: Of course VPC subnets allow this kind of routing. It's a subnet. It's a layer 3 network between each of these hosts. How could it *not* allow it? It's not VPC that's preventing this from working; it's software on one of your boxen. Sounds like a firewall problem. You're probably filtering ICMP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally got it: disable Source/dest check.  The default is "enabled" which will discard any incoming packet if the destination address does not match the instance address.  This of course prevents a router from working.

Comment: I banged my head for hours because of this frickin option. I would upvote you 10 times if I could.

Comment: Weird this didn't help me... Disabling the check still leads to no route to host.

Comment: same here @Oktav I was beginning to doubt my profession ;)